# Can I use the JBoss CXF configuration with Jetty for integration tests?

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, jboss, jetty, cxf

We are implementing JAXB SOAP services that will be deployed on JBoss/CXF. I can write integration tests that use Jetty internally (instantiating Endpoints directly or using the Jetty xml file http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jetty-configuration.html ), but is it possible for Jetty and JBoss to use the same configuration so we don't have to maintain two different configs?